# Syntax when looking for an arraylist element

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax

Ok so, I have a fillhand method that is supposed to get cards from a shuffled deck and add the cards one by one through the top method while also sorting them by suits. The top method saves the card at shuffledDeck at index 0 to a variable, removes the index at 0, and then returns the card. So i added the first card, then its suppose to check if the next card that top returns is of a different suit, if it is then add it to the array list, if it is of the same suit then add it to the arraylist but, in order of ranks within that suit. As of now, where it is supposed to check if the handArray contains the upcoming card's suit == false is not working.

```
    public ArrayList fillHand(ArrayList Array, int handSize)
{
    ArrayList<Card> shuffledDeck = Array;                                       

    handArray.add(deck.top(shuffledDeck));                                        

    for (int i = 0; i < handSize + 1; i++)
    {
        if (handArray.contains(shuffledDeck.get(i).getSuit()) == false)
        {
            handArray.add(deck.top(shuffledDeck));  
        }
    }
     return handArray; 
}
```

Comment: Post your code instead of describing it, and add expected and actual output.

Comment: Have a look at Java 8 streams, then post some code describing a *specific* problem if you encounter one. Here's a good article to get you started: https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment: Not clear. Can you please be precise

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code, I'll assume that Deck is a class with two attributes(rank and suit).

You'll want to create a method for this class that makes it print itself(i.e. "Ace of Spades" or "Jack of Hearts")
You'll also need a method that returns the suit.

From there you iterate over your arraylist and call that method on each node that satisfies the required suit

Edit, since code was posted:

The logic itself seems flawed, you're iterating over the handSize, checking if the suit **number** is in the handArray. This is a major issue, as handArray is an array of **Card**, not an array of **int**.

There are multiple ways to fix this, the simpler ones are:

**Simplest:** iterate over the handArray manually, checking if the suit matches with any of the card's

**Faster:** creating an array of size 4, with all values initialized as false, representing whether or not a suit is in the handArray.

Now that the if statement is dealt with, we must fix it's code. As of now, you're checking if the i suit is in the Array, and adding the **top** card to it.

The best course of action here would be ditching the for loop, replacing it with something like this:

```
while(ArrayList.size()){
    /* code */
}
```

This will loop the array due to the way that top works, since it removes the top card

Comment: You'll simply need to loop over the array then, verify card.getSuit() == value, and call the printing method on card if it is valid

Comment: I don't know if it is going to make a difference but i posted my code so far.

Comment: I edited the answer, I recommend following the simpler course of action, along with the while loop, since the alternative would be parsing the for from last to first, which in my experience is much more troublesome